# Error 3021, no current record has been found, Query data from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm writing a function in Excel VBA which will be called to extract data from an Access database, I'm using ADO connection. The function Get_g_gtop has parameters defined as bellow. Now, I try to use a command object to get the value from recordset, however, I got the error message 3021 : Either BOF or EOF is true, or current record has been deleted. Requested operations requires a current record.   The debug points to the line : Get_g_gtop = rst.Fields(0).Value.

Is there anything wrong with the SQL statement to query in Access? Any advice would be highly appreciate!

Bing

Function Get_g_gtop(ByVal VehType As String, ByVal Speed As Single) As Variant

```
Dim Dbfilepath As String

Dbfilepath = "C:\Users\sevenice\Desktop\EM Database.accdb"

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & " Data Source=" & Dbfilepath & ";" & "Persist Security Info =False;"

'Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Dim QueryStr As String
Dim S As Single

If StrComp(VehType, "LDV") * StrComp(VehType, "LDT") * StrComp(VehType, "LHD<=14K") * StrComp(VehType, "LHD<=19.5K") = 0 Then
   S = 35.6
   'QueryStr = "SELECT [g/gtop] FROM [EM Database].[N (t) Data] WHERE [Vehicle Category]= "" & VehType & "" AND S = 35.6 " & " AND [Speed Lower] <= " & Speed & " AND [Speed Upper] >= " & Speed & ";"

   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [g/gtop] FROM [EM Database].[N (t) Data] WHERE [Vehicle Category]= "" &  VehType & "" AND S = 35.6 " & " AND [Speed Lower] <= " & Speed & " AND [Speed Upper] >= " & Speed & ";"
   'rst.Open QueryStr, cnn

   Set rst = cmd.Execute

   Get_g_gtop = rst.Fields(0).Value

ElseIf StrComp(VehType, "MHD") * StrComp(VehType, "HHD") * StrComp(VehType, "Urban Bus") = 0 Then
   S = 26.7
   QueryStr = "SELECT [g/gtop] FROM [EM Database].[N (t) Data] WHERE [Vehicle Category]=" & VehType & " AND S = 26.7 " & " AND [Speed Lower] <= " & Speed & " AND [Speed Upper] >=" & Speed & ";"
   rst.Open QueryStr, cnn
   Get_g_gtop = rst.Fields(0).Value

End If
```

End Function

Comment: This would be easier for us to troubleshoot if you stripped your code sample down to only the minimum needed to reproduce the problem, and split those long lines so we needn't scroll the browser window to read them.

Comment: @HansUp: ... or if they *extended* the code sample to include SQL DDL and SQL DML to recreate the tables and sample data to reproduce the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

After you open the recordset (`Set rst = cmd.Execute`) you will have to check whether it contains any data, before you try to access that data, for example:

```
if not rst.EOF then
'do your stuff with the data
end if
```

[Reference on w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_bofeof.asp)

The error you are receiving indicates that you are not geting any records from your SELECT-Statement. 
Check it as suggested by HansUp.